# Nothing happens when clicking search button on bootsrap and .net core

Tags: asp.net-core, bootstrap-4

I am trying to learn .net core and what I want to do is: I have a search bar and a GetDetail function in controller. I want to trigger that function when clicking search button according to text in form. But when I click button, nothing happens. I did not complete the trigger part but even if I simply redirect to another page with href, also nothing happens. Here is my search bar view code which taken from sbadmin2:

```
<div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-6 p-3">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control bg-light border-0 small" placeholder="Input" aria-label="Search" aria-describedby="basic-addon2" id="code">                                           
                        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" action="/Books/GetDetail?">
                            <i class="fas fa-search fa-sm"></i>
                        </button>                   
                </div>
            </div>         
        </div>
```

and the function I want to trigger is a get request:

```
public IActionResult GetDetail(string codes)
        {
            var request = $"?codes={codes}";
            var products = _httpTool.HttpGetAsync<List<Products>>($"{AppSettings.ApiUrl}/GetProducts{request}");
            var productList = products.Result.ToList();
            return Json(productList);
        }
```

Why nothing is happening and how can I achieve this?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like this:-

```
<form method="post" asp-action="GetDetail">
  //clarify code

   <input type="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-outline-primary mt-1"/>

 //clarify code

</form>
```

```
 [HttpPost]
public IActionResult GetDetail(string codes)
        {
            var request = $"?codes={codes}";
            var products = _httpTool.HttpGetAsync<List<Products>>($"{AppSettings.ApiUrl}/GetProducts{request}");
            var productList = products.Result.ToList();
            return Json(productList);
        }
```

After clicking `Search`you see something will happen.

Comment: Yes, I made debugger visit the GetDetail finally, which is enough for me. Thanks.